# Python pandas convert list of comma separated values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of strings which looks like this:

```
["Name: Alice, Department: HR, Salary: 60000", "Name: Bob, Department: Engineering, Salary: 45000"]
```

I would like to convert this list into a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Name | Department | Salary
--------------------------
Alice | HR | 60000

Bob | Engineering | 45000
```

What would be the easiest way to go about this?
My gut says throw the data into a CSV and separate titles with regex "^.*:", but there must be a simpler way

Comment: This is pretty simple.  So, before we give you the answer, what have you done to find the answer yourself?  *Hint:* It is a comma delimited string array of k=>v pairs (delimited by `:`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With some string processing you can get a list of dicts and pass that to the DataFrame constructor:

```
lst = ["Name: Alice, Department: HR, Salary: 60000", 
       "Name: Bob, Department: Engineering, Salary: 45000"]
pd.DataFrame([dict([kv.split(': ') for kv in record.split(', ')]) for record in lst])
Out: 
    Department   Name Salary
0           HR  Alice  60000
1  Engineering    Bob  45000
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it this way:

```
In [271]: s
Out[271]:
['Name: Alice, Department: HR, Salary: 60000',
 'Name: Bob, Department: Engineering, Salary: 45000']

In [272]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(re.sub(r'\s*(Name|Department|Salary):\s*', r'', '~'.join(s))),
     ...:             names=['Name','Department','Salary'],
     ...:             header=None,
     ...:             lineterminator=r'~'
     ...: )
     ...:
Out[272]:
    Name   Department  Salary
0  Alice           HR   60000
1    Bob  Engineering   45000
```

Answer (score 3):

a little creative

```
s.str.extractall(r'(?P<key>[^,]+)\s*:(?P<value>[^,]+)') \
    .reset_index('match', drop=True) \
    .set_index('key', append=True).value.unstack()
```

[image]

***setup***

```
l = ["Name: Alice, Department: HR, Salary: 60000",
     "Name: Bob, Department: Engineering, Salary: 45000"]
s = pd.Series(l)
```